# Несколько контекстов в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Когда я только начал изучать спринг, со spring context, нам показывали как можно создавать несколько контекстов.

Сейчас я перешёл на Spring Boot, и не могу понять, а может ли тут быть несколько конфигурационных файлов для контекста? Если да, где их создавать/прописывать(определённый пакет?)? Или в буте только один контекст на проект, как диспатчер сервлет для сервлетов?

Если можно создать несколько контекстов, тогда ещё вопрос, как спринг поймёт из какого из них нужно инжектить компонент? Это нужно с какой-то аннотацией прописывать (чтоб указать из какого контекста брать)?

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

Comment: зачем два контекста?

Comment: Да преподаватель на курсе по джаве запутал меня, сейчас разобрался наконец то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы похоже путаете конфигурационные файлы и контексты.

При создании контекста можно использовать один файл конфигурации (или java класс конфигурации), а можно несколько - при этом все равно будет создан один контекст. Далее, в spring boot контекст, обычно, не создается вручную (я вообще не уверен, что это возможно). Его создание спрятано, можно только влиять на то, откуда берется конфигурация.

Конфигурация spring boot - это всегда java конфигурация (все классы, которые находятся в пакете приложения или в подпакетах помеченные `@Configuration`), но можно использовать:

1. `@ImportResource` на любом из классов конфигурации, для того чтоб подключить дополнительные файлы с xml конфигурацией.
2. `@Import` для подключения дополнительных классов java конфигурации в случае, когда они находятся в других пакетах.

По умолчанию создается один контекст, т.е. вот такой код, создаст один контекст:

```
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
```

Но можно использовать [SpringApplicationBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html) для того, чтоб создать несколько контекстов объедененых в иерархию:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(ParentConfig.class)
   .child(ChildConfig.class)
   .run(args);
```

Или вообще два независимых контекста (и значит два независимых spring boot приложения в одном java процессе):

```
SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .sources(ParentConfig.class);

applicationBuilder.child(Application1Config.class).run(args);
applicationBuilder.child(Application2Config.class).run(args);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ!

Comment: Хочу уточнить, контекст вообще всегда один?

Comment: По умолчанию - один. Добавил подробности об этом  в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо что помогли разобраться